# Recursion counters

Tags: java, recursion

I have the following code to serialize and deserialize a binary tree. Serialization works fine, but deserialization is incorrect. I am struggling to understand how my array index counter "i" should be set for deserialization. I would really appreciate it if you can help me understand this.

```
public class TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;

    TreeNode(int x) {
        val = x;
    }
}

public String serialize(TreeNode root) {
    StringBuffer serial = new StringBuffer();
    helperSerialize(root, serial);
    return serial.toString();
}


public void helperSerialize(TreeNode node, StringBuffer serial) {
    if (node == null) {
        serial.append("null ");
        return;
    }
    serial.append(new Integer(node.val).toString() + " ");
    helperSerialize(node.left, serial);
    helperSerialize(node.right, serial);
}

public TreeNode deSerialize(TreeNode root, String s) {
    String[] split = s.split("\\s+");
    root = deSerialize( split, 0);
    return root;
}

public TreeNode deSerialize( String[] s, int i) {
    if(i >= s.length || s[i].equals("null"))
        return null;
    else {
        int v = (int) s[i].charAt(0) - '0';
       TreeNode root = new TreeNode(v);
        root.left = deSerialize( s, ++i);
        i = i +1; // i should be incremented for next recursion
        root.right = deSerialize( s, ++i);
        return root;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your fundamental source of confusion is trying to deserialize in a conceptually different way than you serialized. Your appending integer tokens when serializing. Instead of this strange indexed base thing you're doing for deserialization, just keep parsing and consuming the first token in the stringbuffer. Perhaps even parse it into a list of ints before deserializing, where it's easier to pop the front off the list as you consume it.

Comment: what is happening is you pass i by value and not by reference thus making the tree have recurrent values in every branch, try giving a int[] in parameter containing the index.

Answer (score 0):

try this: (as example implementation to make the index work)

```
public TreeNode deSerialize(TreeNode root, String s) {
    String[] split = s.split("\\s+");
    root = deSerialize( split, new int[1]{0});
    return root;
}

public TreeNode deSerialize( String[] s, int[] i) {
    if(i[0] >= s.length || s[i[0]].equals("null"))
        return null;
    else {
        int v = (int) s[i[0]].charAt(0) - '0';
       TreeNode root = new TreeNode(v);
        root.left = deSerialize( s, ++i[0]);
        root.right = deSerialize( s, ++i[0]);
        return root;
    }
}
```

this allows passing the index by reference thus not cloning the branches.

Edit:

your algorythm is as follows:

```
    A
   / \
  B   C
 / \ / \
D  E F  G
```

you serialize a: 
A B D null null E null null C F null null G null null 
you deserialize a: 
A B D null null null D null null 
with the array based iterator: 
A B D null null E null null C F null null G null null

but your 
        int v = (int) s[i].charAt(0) - '0';
is wrong, since it only allows one char numbers, use Integer.parse() instead.

since you didn't provide your input/output, i cannot see which is the error, but if you do the incermentation by reference and the parsing, you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks! but this is passing by index as well and have the same incorrect answer.

Comment: no, now you pass the pointer to the array containing the index, you may wanna tweak the incrementations, but you have to use the references or use an incrementor object.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a `Scanner` instead of pre-parsing the full string. Then you don't need to worry about the index at all.

Here's some code that seems to work. (Sorry, I renamed and rearranged a few things to make it easier to build a running sample.)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;

    TreeNode(int x) {
        val = x;
    }

    TreeNode(int x, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
        val = x;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public String serialize() {
        StringBuffer serial = new StringBuffer();
        serializeHelper(this, serial);
        return serial.toString();
    }

    private static void serializeHelper(TreeNode node, StringBuffer serial) {
        if (node == null) {
            serial.append("null ");
            return;
        }
        serial.append(new Integer(node.val).toString() + " ");
        serializeHelper(node.left, serial);
        serializeHelper(node.right, serial);
    }

    public static TreeNode deserialize(String serialized) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(serialized);
        return deserializeHelper(scanner);
    }

    private static TreeNode deserializeHelper(Scanner scanner) {
        String value = null;

        if (scanner.hasNext()) {
            value = scanner.next();
        }
        if (value == null || value.equals("null")) {
            return null;
        }

        return new TreeNode(Integer.parseInt(value),
                            deserializeHelper(scanner),
                            deserializeHelper(scanner));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeNode root = new TreeNode(1,
            new TreeNode(2,
                new TreeNode(3),
                new TreeNode(4)),
            null);

        String serialized = root.serialize();
        System.out.println(serialized);

        TreeNode deserialized = deserialize(serialized);
        // 1 2 3 null null 4 null null null
        System.out.println(deserialized.left.right.val);
        // 4
        System.out.println(deserialized.serialize());
        // 1 2 3 null null 4 null null null 
    }
}
```